# Sum of Rows in List in R

Tags: r, list, sum, rows

I want to find rows in which sum of rows give 3 among these columns: 
2nd (Q-1_A-4), 3th (Q-4_A-1) and 5th (Q-9_A-1). Input and desired output is at the below.

Input:

```
ID   Q-1_A-4   Q-4_A-1   Q-6_A-1  Q-9_A-1

122       1       1        0       1
123       0       1        1       0
124       0       0        1       0 
125       0       0        0       0   
126       1       1        1       1
```

Desired output:

```
ID no 122 and 126 gives 3 as a row sum for these 3 columns: 
(2nd (Q-1_A-4), 3th (Q-4_A-1) and 5th (Q-9_A-1))
```

Comment: You should check your example. I don't think row ID 126 gives a row sum of 3, and as a result it's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @RyanThompson -  row ID 126 does give a sum of 3 for the 2nd, 3rd and 5th columns. Please read again.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Oh, I see, it's only considering a subset of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on a subset of columns, check if the sum is 3, and use that to subset the rows of 'df1'.

```
df1[rowSums(df1[c(2,3,5)])==3,]
```

Comment: How I can specify 3 specific columns for summation? @akrun

Comment: @serenade Just subset the dataset by the column index `df1[c(2,3,5)]` and do the `rowSums` and check if that is equal to 3, then subset the rows based on that index.

Comment: But I have this error: Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) :  'x' must be numeric  @akhun

Comment: @serenade Do you have a `data.frame`?  Do you have numeric columns in the dataset?  If not it should be converted to numeric i.e. `df1[c(2, 3, 5)] <- lapply(df1[c(2,3,5)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` iin case it is `factor` class

Comment: thank you, I have solved. Thank you for your kindly help @akhun